# moving fonts command

Tags: mv

I am trying to create a script to run from a Casper Server, I have managed to get the script to capture the current logged in user and I would like to move the fonts out of their ~/Library/Fonts/ folder.

I just keep getting an error that the folder does not exist, I think it is because I am trying to go to the hidden library folder, originally I thought it was because it couldn't find the "FontsRemoved" folder so I changed that to a variable too and I am still getting the error. Can someone assist with how I should maybe be calling this? I need to set user folders back to default for SOX compliance and I would rather have a backup of the fonts rather than overwriting the folder with a DMG of the folder, just in case there are fonts that the user require.

```
mkdir -m 777 /Users/Shared/FontsRemoved/

user=`/bin/ls -la /dev/console | /usr/bin/cut -d " " -f 4`

fontsfolder=/Users/Shared/FontsRemoved/

"mv /$user/Library/Fonts/* $fontsfolder"
```

Comment: Here is the error I am getting btw:   /bin/bash: line 7: mv /room.one/Library/Fonts/* /Users/Shared/FontsRemoved/: No such file or directory

Comment: `mv /Users/$user/Library/Fonts/* $fontsfolder"`

Comment: @MrTrigger Add that to the question, not a comment

Comment: Don't put the command to execute inside quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last command in your script is

```
"mv /$user/Library/Fonts/* $fontsfolder"
```

You get `mv /room.one/Library/Fonts/* /Users/Shared/FontsRemoved/: No such file or directory` because it tries to find a command with that name, including spaces.

That's because you have put the whole line in double quotes.

Instead, do

```
mv /"$user"/Library/Fonts/* "$fontsfolder"
```

or

```
mv /home/"$user"/Library/Fonts/* "$fontsfolder"
```

or

```
mv /Users/"$user"/Library/Fonts/* "$fontsfolder"
```

depending on where your home directories are located.

Comment: Thanks so much, the last line worked for me, that was driving me crazy!